# Выполнение агентов на cron (Bitrix)

Tags: битрикс, cron

Необходимо настроить выполнение агентов через cron. Все время ошибка в проверке системы (Выполнение агентов на cron: Ошибка! Не настроен запуск cron_events.php на cron, последний агент отработал больше суток назад.). Писал в тех. поддержку хостинга, ответили, что с их стороны все хорошо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а в самом кроне запись сделали?

Comment: Да, у хостера в планировщики заданий прописал выполнить php : /home/XXX/xxx.ru/docs/bitrix/modules/main/tools/cron_events.php

Comment: Вот [тут](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2943) под заголовком "Обобщённое решение" - это вам поможет